# Messages are not publish to elastic search when the grok filter maches

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I'm using the below config as a logstash config. When the grok filter matches a log entry, I can't see any messages in the elastic search (i.e. they are not published). Are there any issues with my configuration?

```
input {
   beats {
   port => 5044
}
}

filter {
  if [message] =~ "\tat" {
    grok {
      match => ["message", "^(\tat)"]
      add_tag => ["stacktrace"]
    }
 }

 grok {
   break_on_match => false
   match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} \[%{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} \] %{GREEDYDATA:msg}" }
   match => { "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\]  %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} %{GREEDYDATA:msg}" }
   match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} %{GREEDYDATA:msg}" }
   add_field => ["environment" , "%{[kubernetes][namespace]}"]
   add_field => ["container" , "%{[kubernetes][container][name]}"]
   add_field => ["pod_ip" , "%{[kubernetes][pod][ip]}"]
   add_field => ["deployment", "msa"]
}
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://example.com:9200","http://example2.com:9200"]
    index => "%{[kubernetes][labels][elk_index_prefix]}.%{[kubernetes][namespace]}-%{+YYYY.ww}"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```